# nautilus disk properties: gray color

Tags: nautilus

Silly question maybe, but I wonder why for this pen disk, what is the meaning of that gray color in nautilus properties window?

[image: nautilus properties window]

Is it dark matter? :)

Notice that the legend only shows the blue and white colors.

I have formatted the disk using ext4. This is the gnome-disk-utility:

[image: gnome-disk-utility]

(Sorry for the screenshot being in Portuguese. But it seemed pretty obvious which was which to bother changing the system language...)

UPDATE: Here is a gparted screenshot of the disk:

[image: gparted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dark gray area are the 5%, reserved for 
privileged processes. For a detailed explanation see below.

[image]

Change the value via

```
$ sudo tune2fs -m 2 /dev/sdd1
tune2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
Setting reserved blocks percentage to 2% (38394 blocks)
```

and see the difference

[image]

---

from `man tune2fs`

```
-m reserved-blocks-percentage

Set the percentage of the filesystem which may only be allocated by privileged
processes. Reserving some number of filesystem blocks for use by privileged
processes is done to avoid filesystem fragmentation, and to allow system
daemons, such as syslogd(8), to continue to function correctly after non-privileged
processes are prevented from writing to the filesystem. Normally, the default
percentage of reserved blocks is 5%.
```

Comment: Very cool. But I wonder what you mean exactly by "reserved for your root user" - are you referring to things such as the file system allocation table?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thank you. I have used `-m 0` because this is a USB disk. Hope it is okay. :)